# RxJava Error Handling - How to add error callback on Flowable stream

Tags: rx-java

While coding an RxJava POC program i’m facing an Exception that contain some recommendation of better handling:

The recommendation advises to implement the onError callback. I tried doing so (see screenshot) but the callback never gets invoked so i cant really swallow this Exception hence my stream get shut down.
By the way, after debigging the Exception stack trace is see that it get thrown due to "no more" elements on the buffer. Isn't that a tough approach? (see second screenshot)[image]

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling | io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: RST_STREAM closed stream. HTTP/2 error code: INTERNAL_ERROR
at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.LambdaSubscriber.onError(LambdaSubscriber.java:79)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.checkTerminated(FlowableFlattenIterable.java:395)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drain(FlowableFlattenIterable.java:255)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onError(FlowableFlattenIterable.java:181)
at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.BasicFuseableSubscriber.onError(BasicFuseableSubscriber.java:101)
at com.daml.grpc.adapter.client.rs.BufferingResponseObserver.lambda$onError$3(BufferingResponseObserver.java:81)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

[image]

Comment: When you picked the `onErrorXXX` method, did you ignore the returned new flowable and went on with the original `transactions` reference? If so, please read [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#simple-background-computation).

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd. that helped. Indeed after using the returned flowable from onErrorReturn the callback is triggered. However, since its a runtime exception i'm having a hard time swalling it (ignoring it) hence it causes the stream to break. Can you advise how to overcome such error in a way to allow the stream to still communicate?