# RxJava - How to "swallow" an Observer runtime Exception using doOnError() callback

Tags: java, rx-java

While coding an RxJava POC program i’m facing a Runtime Exception as shown below.

Thanks to @akarnokd (in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71497550/rxjava-error-handling-how-to-add-error-callback-on-flowable-stream)) i was able to intercept the error on my doOnError() callback existing on the Flowable object.

The problem is that even if i intercepts its process i cant really "swallow" (ignore) it and its effectively shutting down the stream from the Observable to my Observer.

Here is the Exception followed by the code:

> io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling | io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: RST_STREAM closed stream. HTTP/2 error code: INTERNAL_ERROR
> at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
> at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
> at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.LambdaSubscriber.onError(LambdaSubscriber.java:79)
> at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.checkTerminated(FlowableFlattenIterable.java:395)
> at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drain(FlowableFlattenIterable.java:255)
> at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onError(FlowableFlattenIterable.java:181)
> at io.reactivex.internal.subscribers.BasicFuseableSubscriber.onError(BasicFuseableSubscriber.java:101)
> at com.daml.grpc.adapter.client.rs.BufferingResponseObserver.lambda$onError$3(BufferingResponseObserver.java:81)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

[image]

The runtime exception is thrown due to the below condition (found during debugging of the Exception's flow)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3):

`.doOnError` does not "swallow" Exceptions, it just executes a side-effect when one is emitted. You can use `onErrorResumeNext` to replace an Exception with some other `Flowable` of your choice, which will keep the Exception from being propagated downstream.

But keep in mind that even if you do that, the upstream `Flowable` will still be terminated, because it will have emitted an error, which is a terminal signal. So in your example above, replacing `doOnError` with `onErrorResumeNext` will not keep the `Flowable` returned by `getTransactions` from ceasing to emit new items. Keeping the `getTransactions` `Flowable` emitting when it encounters an Exception would require changing its internal implementation. Even then, it may not be possible, depending on the specifics of the Exception it hit.